# where to write the SetExpressCheckout method in expresscheckout paypal

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am using paypal express checkout and it is working fine I am getting the access token in the window but i don't know where to write the setexpresscheckout code.

```
<form method="post" action="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" >
<input type="hidden" name="USER" value="abcd_api1.gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="PWD" value="13432424" />
<input type="hidden" name="SIGNATURE" value="sdf-hi0xxxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="76.0" />
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTACTION" value="Authorization" />
<input type="hidden" name="AMT" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="RETURNURL" value="http://www.steadfastglobal.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="http://www.google.com" />
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="METHOD" value="SetExpressCheckout" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Express Checkout doesn't work with actual HTML forms like this.  You need to use cURL or some other method of POSTing data to the PayPal endpoints so that you can grab the response easily and proceed accordingly.

Are you working with PHP?  If so, check out my [PHP library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It will make the Express Checkout calls very simple for you.  It sets everything up for you so all you have to do is fill in the parameter values, and if you want to study the actual class file you can see how it makes the calls to PayPal using cURL and handles the response.